# Unordered list menu unable to position it correctly + unable to center the list items within the unordered list

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the fiddle below:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TE8hD/

In it you can see my problems:

- The list items within the `<ul>` are not centered as there is a big margin to the left while there is no gap at all to the right.
- Also the `<ul>` itself cannot be properly positioned the way I want it to. I want it to be 200px from the right and 0px from the bottom. However when I try this I can only get the `right` property to work.

I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours, changing everything from position, float, display, margin, padding etc. Nothing seems to do the trick, if I could get some help solving this it would make my day.

Comment: Are those px value widthd absolutely necessary? http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/TE8hD/3/

Comment: `ul` / `li` / plus the margin values. if all you want to do is center the `ul` and the `li` there are easier ways.

Comment: I'm gonna remove some properties, so all of them are probably not necessary no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

To your .dropdown class.

And look into implementing a reset.css file, which typically resets margin, padding, and other properties on a lot of elements so that you have a blank slate when creating your CSS.

Also, you seem to lack an understanding of what position: relative and position: absolute do. Do some research on that. But if you want your UL to be positioned absolutely at the bottom of its containing element (.header), then .header needs to have position: relative and .dropdown needs position: absolute;

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TE8hD/2/

Comment: That takes care of the gap to the left of the list, however `bottom: 0;` still doesn't work.. Any ideas?

Comment: I know how positioning works, just been changing a lot so might have forgotten to change it back to what it was originally. Apologies for that.

Comment: Ey, instead of asking a new question I thought maybe you could help me out directly. I implemented a reset.css file, however, the reset file contains `font-family: inherit;` which resets my `font-family: "tahoma", "arial", "sans serif"` in the `body` of the CSS. How do I control this? Do I have to write `font-family: "tahoma", "arial", "sans serif"` in the class/id that I want to use it on when using a reset file or like how does it work?